# Check file before to download

Tags: android, android-file, android-download-manager

We suppose i have a local file in my sdcard, that an `Android` app did downloaded and stored, in any time in the remote server this file can change (the content) although the file name is the same.

How can i check the file versions without download the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

304 Not Modified
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Get the date from the version of the file on the SD card and ask the server if / for versions newer than that date.